# How to remove page numbers and dots from a minitoc created by the titletoc package?

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

In the code below, how to remove page numbers and dots from the minitoc (not the main TOC)? I didn't find any commands or options in the documentation to do that.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}
\section{Large Degree Isogenies}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
\section{Cassels Pairing}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
\section{The Hidden Root Problem}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be so easy if you would use `tocloft`, but alas, it's `titletoc`